# socialregistration access token error

Tags: django, facebook, socialregistration

I am using django-socialregistration and when I click the facebook button, it is redirected to facebook and the user is requested for the permissions. After the permissions are given, the redirection is done to my site and I get the following error:

```
Credentials could not be validated, the provider returned no access token.
```

I don't know what it means.. What is it that I should do?

I don't understand anything in [this](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration/issues/160).

Comment: which version of django-socialregistration r u using ?

Comment: @PriyankPatel: don't know. How do I find out? I installed through pip

Comment: Execute this `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and check `requirements.txt` file .

Comment: @PriyankPatel: 0.5.10